# geoserver.war deployment error in Tomcat8

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-18.04, tomcat8, geoserver, catalina

I am trying to use geoserver-2.17.2-war on Apache Tomcat 8 in ubuntu 18.04 server.

I am able to upload geoserver.war file to the application server’s webapps directory.
However, I am not able to start geoserver. The error message got is:
*FAIL - Application at context path [/geoserver] could not be started*.
[image]

The tutorials I follow [1,2,3] say that
"uploading geoserver.war file to the application server’s webapps directory is enough to deploy the application". Is there any configuration that I am missing? I would appreciate if you could provide links to some working examples.

Here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/b64u383j9s07wb4/catalina.out?dl=0) is the log generated while trying to start geoserver (Start button click), the log for catalina.out
Thank You.

1. https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/war.html
2. [Deploy geoserver on tomcat 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545078/deploy-geoserver-on-tomcat-8?rq=1)
3. https://docs.geonode.org/en/3.0/install/advanced/core/index.html#geonode-installation

Comment: Using Apache Tomcat 9.0.27 (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-18-04/) went smoothly wihout issue

Comment: whatever went wrong was before the log file you provide - probably a memory issue